# Replace occurrences of characters in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Values in the column `Name_Orig` look something like this:
`**Ang-Stl-A36-6X4X.5**Angle,A36*,4X6X1/2****`

I want

- First occurrence of ** to be replaced by Xx_
- Second occurrence of ** to be replaced by a_
- Replace all other * are to be with space

This is not a complete table, yet, these set of condition go in Common Table Expression(CTE)

I can replace the first occurence of **
For the second and the third point the query doesn't work

```
CASE 
When Name_Orig LIKE '**%' THEN 'Xx_'+ SUBSTRING(Name_Orig, 3, LEN(Name_Orig)-2)
WHEN CHARINDEX('**', Name_Orig, CHARINDEX('**', Name_Orig) + 1) > 0 THEN 
                REPLACE(STUFF(Name_Orig, CHARINDEX('**', Name_Orig, CHARINDEX('**', Name_Orig) + 1), 2, 'a_'), '*', ' ')
            ELSE Name_Orig
END
```

Using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: use `charindex()` to find first 2 occurrence and replace with the required string. for the rest, use `replace()`

Comment: FYI, 2005 ran out of support almost a *decade* ago. You ***need*** to get that instance upgraded, and it's going to be *hard*, as no shpport e versions of SQL Server support restores from 2005.

Comment: @ITBrute how did you get on? Its customary and polite to report back when people answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by Squirrel, use `patindex` to find the first and second `**`'s and then `replace` to remove any remaining `8`s.

```
select a.TestValue, replace(e.NewString,'*',' ')
from (
  values ('**Ang-Stl-A36-6X4X.5**Angle,A36*,4X6X1/2****')
) a (TestValue)
cross apply (
  values (patindex('%**%', a.TestValue))
) b (FirstPat)
cross apply (
  values (
    case
    when b.FirstPat > 0 then substring(a.TestValue, 1, b.FirstPat - 1) + 'Xx_' + substring (a.TestValue, b.FirstPat + 2, len(a.TestValue))
    else a.TestValue
    end
  )
) c (NewString)
cross apply (
  values (patindex('%**%', c.NewString))
) d (SecondPat)
cross apply (
  values (
    case
    when d.SecondPat > 0 then substring(c.NewString, 1, d.SecondPat - 1) + 'a_' + substring (c.NewString, d.SecondPat + 2, len(c.NewString)) 
    else c.NewString
    end
  )
) e (NewString);
```

Returns:

| TestValue | NewValue |
| --- | --- |
| **Ang-Stl-A36-6X4X.5**Angle,A36*,4X6X1/2**** | Xx_Ang-Stl-A36-6X4X.5a_Angle,A36 ,4X6X1/2 |

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PVbep7zk)

Comment: Unless I recall incorrectly, I dont think the `VALUES` table constructor existed in 2005.

Comment: Arrr, oh well if OP comes back I'll re-write it

Comment: I'll admit, my memoyof that edition is fuzzy, so it *might* have been 2005 added them. I *think* it at least had `APPLY`.

Comment: Yeah I was writing simple SQL back then